# Easiest way to utilize coldfusion returned json object (from query)

Tags: jquery, json, coldfusion, cfc

I've got a `CFC` thats returning a query object in JSON format, looks like this:

```
{
 "COLUMNS":["CMADDR","CMBILL","CMCRLIMIT","CMCRREVIEW","CMCRTERMS","CMCRUPDATE","CMCURR"],
 "DATA":[[1.2004856E7,3.2004856E7,0,"January, 01 1959 00:00:00","N\/30",null,"USD",null,false,false,false,"",0,"","US", ...],
        [2.2045505E7,3.2004583E7,4000,"January, 01 1959 00:00:00","1\/10N30",null,"USD",null,false,false....]]
}
```

*data has been shortened just for structure sake*

But I am given back a jSON object with columns & data.

What is the best way to access this data using jQuery? Excuse my inexperience, as in the past I've just used more simple structures, and I've usually defined them myself, this way the CFC returns this output to me and I'm forced to consume it and iterate through it with end result being a table of data.

I've tried the following, but get undefined values so far:

```
// ajax calls .. this is on success..
// ...
function(data) {
    //alert('got data back! \n'+data);
    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
    $.each(obj, function(index, itemData) {
    $('#modal-table-listing > tbody:last').append('<tr>' +
        '<td>[Select]</td>' +
        '<td>'+ itemData.cmAddr +'</td>' +
        '<td>'+ itemData.adName +'</td>' +
        '<td>'+ itemData.adState +' - '+ itemData.adCity +' - '+ itemData.adZip +'</td></tr>');
    });

    console.log(obj);
}
```

I'd love to use the `columns` object to reference the relevant data, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your data structure, you really want to be looping through `obj.data`. Your returned object has TWO properties. One describes your columns, the next is an array of results.

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
$.each(obj.DATA, function(index, itemData) {
$('tbody:last').append('<tr>' +
    '<td>[Select]</td>' +
    '<td>'+ itemData[0]+'</td>' +
    '<td>'+ itemData[1] +'</td>' +
    '<td>'+ itemData[2] +' - '+ itemData[3] +' - '+ itemData[4] +'</td></tr>');
});
```

I don't know what columns are which index, given the data. But you can figure it out via `obj.columns.indexOf('CMADDR');` or something like that, that will give you 0.

**Edit**
You could probably easily write a quick map reduce with Underscore.js to get exactly the format you wanted. Something like

```
myData = _.map(obj.data, function(row){ 
             var item = {"column1" : row[0],
                         "column2" : row[1]}; 
              return item;
             }); `
```

This would result in myData being an array of objects with named properties.

Comment: I accepted this, but just ended up using the index to reference fields returned (result was I cut down my returned columns into something easily managed). I was hoping there was a quick/straight forward way to map the object to use columns without includeing things like `underscore.js` as I haven't used that lib before.